# Unknown filesystem at grub prompt

Tags: grub2

I am getting grub rescue promt > 
After reading the forum have realised that I have unknowingly deleted the grub that's the reason I am not able to boot ..
Grub rescue > ls
Gives me 
Hd0 hd0,msdos5 hd0,msdos3 hd0,msdos2 hd0,msdos1

To check which part has ubuntu I tried listing all but for all I get "unknow filesystem" 
Please tell how should I resolve this !!

Answer (score 2):

Prepare a Boot-able Live USB stick with Ubuntu.

Boot the computer with this Stick.

Open Terminal and type :

```
update-grub.
```

If this does not work then install Boot Repair program from internet on to the pen-drive and run the program.

Run the Program and fix Grub record

Detailed Steps to use, here : [Using Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)